# Trigger application in Android when locked

Tags: android, gps

How would I trigger an application in Android when the device is locked. There would be a sequence of commands (e.g. clicking home/power button 3 times) and I'd like my application to trigger something like sending a gps location.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean "trigger application"? There is no such thing in Android. Common UI patter for notifying user about something is using system notifications for example:
GPS triggers geofence ->
Notification is displayed (with some sound vibration etc.)
User tap notification (and unlocking device before)
Activity is displayed

You can wake the device if it sleep, but you can't unlock it from your code.
Alternative way is to use lock screen widgets to display your information on locked screen.